# Spring service is null in custom ConstraintValidator

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javax.validation

I have spring boot project, a bean using javax validation API.

I'm trying to inject a service in my custom validator for a bean. But the service object is null.
I don't find a complete example that use Spring ConstraintValidator and i don't understand the configuration that some persons made for their integration tests in another topics.

I want to have a validator with constructor injection like this (i don't want to use @Autowired nore javax @Inject) :

```
@Component
public class CustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidCustomValidator, CustomObj> {

private ErreurService erreurService;

public CustomValidator(ErreurService erreurService) {
     this.erreurService=erreurService;
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(CustomObj customObj, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    erreurService.getMessages("");
    return false;
}
}
```

** ErreurService**

```
@Service("ErreurService")
@Transactional
public class ErreurServiceImpl implements ErreurService {//...}
```

With this approach i got an Exception `HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator`

I try something with @Autowired but got always got a NPE.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: you are using `ErreurService` that is never handled and injected by spring, You must use the `@Autowired' annotation or on the constructor or on the property. If on property, yuo can remove the constructor param

Comment: I update the question. `ErreurService` is managed by Spring i have no problem injecting it in others `@services` using constructor injection

Comment: In this case I guess yuo have `@Autowired` near the constructor param; try to give a look or to post the constructor where it's all ok

Comment: You are mixing concepts. A `ConstraintValidation` is a general purpose functionality (not related with Spring, although you can use in that framework) used to validate "generic information": a parameter, method, etc If you need to check something specifically related with `ErreurService` => create a method in that class to do it. In that way, you won't need to deal with DI. Another option is create an specific `ConstraintValidator` to check the information you want to verify (not the "whole service"). Take a look to the link https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the `@Service` annotation on `ErreurService` implementation class? Is it in the package from specified `ComponentScan`?

Comment: Yes, i did it. As you can see in piece of code `@Service` is present on the implementation and the class is scanned